# How to reorder words in sentences

Tags: javascript, html

I have sentences like these:

```
Have I Banana

Have I Apple

Have I Car
```

I need to reorder the words into 2, 1, 3 (the 2nd word go before the 1st) so it becomes normal sentences Example:

```
I have Banana

I have Apple

I have Car
```

My code is like this so far, since I'm new to Javascript - I don't know much:

```
var text = document.getElementById('mytext');
var result = document.getElementById('myresult');
var lines = text.value.split('\n');
result.value = '';
for(i=0; i<lines.length;i++) {
  var line = lines[i];
  var word = line.split(' ');

}
result += word[2]+word[1]+word[3];
```

That code might be completely wrong, I don't know how to split `\n` and `' '` at the same time

Comment: Is it important that the capitalization changes? eg. "Have I Banana" becomes "I have Banana" and the capitalization of "have" changes. If you're *only* asking about reordering the text, maybe edit your question to an example where the words remain exactly the same? (In most programming languages, "have" and "Have" are *not* the same thing.) Edit: Welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: @BSL-5 Thanks, fortunately I just need to switch order of some words that capitalization doesn't matter for one of my school assignment (not computer class). I couldn't find a word switcher online so I decided to code it in html. Plus I learn more coding with it and probably can save me time in the future I need to do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've split by newlines, check to see if the line contains anything. (If empty, just append a new line to the result text.) Split the line by spaces and re-order it. Note that arrays are zero-indexed, not one-indexed, and remember to put spaces between the words when you're appending them. Also make sure to always declare variables before you use them - if you use `i = 0` without declaring it first, like with `let i = 0`, you'll get an error in strict mode.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('mytext');
var result = document.getElementById('myresult');
var lines = text.value.split('\n');
result.value = '';
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var line = lines[i];
  if (!line) {
    result.value += '\n\n';
    continue;
  }
  var word = line.split(' ');
  result.value += word[1] + ' ' + word[0] + ' ' + word[2];
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="mytext">Have I Banana

Have I Apple

Have I Car</textarea>
<textarea id="myresult"></textarea>
```

This could be achieved *much* more concisely with a regular expression: match two words at the beginning of the line, capturing each word, and use a replacer function that switches their position:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('mytext');
var result = document.getElementById('myresult');

result.value = text.value.replace(
  /^(\w+) (\w+)/gm,
  (_, word1, word2) => `${word2} ${word1}`
);
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="mytext">Have I Banana

Have I Apple

Have I Car</textarea>
<textarea id="myresult"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you, I I can't understand your regular expression as it contain $ and { etc that I didn't learn. Would be great to know it though. Can you explain how !line works? I can't understand the logic behind it. How can it be not line if the line is = to line[i] as it has 5 lines and it read the next line everytime i+?

Comment: `${word2} ${word1}` is just a clean way to do string concatenation, it's equivalent to `word2 + ' ' + word1`. The empty string is falsey, so `!line` will evaluate to `true` if the line has no content (lines 2 and 4 in your input).

Answer (score 2):

you already have lines in you code.

```js
    let lines = ["Have I Banana", "Have I Apple", "Have I Car"]

    function getNewLines(lines) {
      let tempResult = [];
      lines.map(function(line) {
        //push each new lines into an array
        tempResult.push(reorder(line));
      });
      return tempResult;
    }

    function reorder(sentence) {
      //store each words into an array using split(" ")
      let array = sentence.split(" ");
      //we delete the two first element of the array starting from position 0
      //we add the 2nd and 1st element of the array at position 0
      array.splice(0, 2, array[1], array[0]);
      //we convert the array into a string using join(" ")
      return array.join(" ");
    }

    let newLines = getNewLines(lines);
    //newLines = ["I Have Banana", "I Have Apple", "I Have Car"]

    function printEachLines(newLines) {
      newLines.map(function (newLine) {
        //console.log each new lines
        console.log(newLine);
      });
    }

    printEachLines(newLines);
```

syntax: `array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2);`

Comment: I put 3 lines but I actually have 1000 lines in my real code you only have 1 line

Comment: I Elliot, I have edited my code to loop trough all the lines. What would you like to do with the output: print it or store it into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

There are much better ways to do this, but here is something simple that should be easy to understand.

First of all, to get the text of an element, use `textContent` instead of `value`.  Also, don't forget that the first item in an array has an index of 0.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('mytext');
var result = document.getElementById('myresult');
var output = [];
var lines = text.textContent.split('\n');
//result.value = '';
for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var line = lines[i];
  var word = line.split(' ');
  var newline = [word[1]];
  newline.push(word[0]);
  newline.push(word[2]);
  output.push(newline.join(' '));
}
result.textContent = output.join('\n');;
```

```html
<pre id="mytext">Have I Banana
Have I Apple
Have I Car</pre>
<pre id="myresult"></pre>
```